# How would Windows XP system restore work on a dual boot PC?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, system, restore, windows-xp

I have a 32-bit Windows XP system that I want to make dual boot with Ubuntu 16.04. My questions are these:
1. If I make a system restore point on XP, would that be able to remove Ubuntu if I didn't like it?
2. Can I use System Restore on XP just to repair the XP functions on a dual boot system?

Comment: Related: [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/q/133533/250300)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. System Restore in Windows functions only within the Windows operating system. Its functionality does not extend to other operating systems that are booted alongside Windows, so you can't use System Restore to remove Ubuntu from a dual boot.
2. grub2 is the default bootloader in a Windows/Ubuntu dual boot system. Since grub is part of Ubuntu, System Restore cannot repair grub. Other than that exception System Restore works exactly the same way in Windows on a dual booted Windows operating system as it does on a single booted Windows operating system. In Windows XP you can use System Restore to restore back to an earlier "snapshot" of some system files by reverting back to the files and settings that were saved in the earlier restore point.

Comment: Thanks, Karel, your answer will help others also!

Comment: @Newbie If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.

Answer (score 1):

1. *If I make a system restore point on XP, would that be able to remove Ubuntu if I didn't like it?*  Answer: NO, The System Restore Tool only works within a Windows NTFS partition. Since Ubuntu won't install to NTFS, it won't.
2. *Can I use System Restore on XP just to repair the XP functions on a dual boot system?* That's a question to ask at https://superuser.com as Windows repair is off topic here. You will get a much more informed answer at https://superuser.com .

Comment: Thanks, that's good for now. If I get the answer to Q#2, I'll post it.